# how do i hide or display a button in my master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am devloping a web application where i am validating users against a set of users in the sql db table.I have a master page and couple of other pages.So when a user 'A' logsinto the application ,my application queries into the sql table an authenticates the user.

My question is that i have a column called role in my sql table.so when user is authenticated based on the role i want to display or not display a button control in my home page.All my logic lies in the code behind of the login page.

Can any one help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the .Visible property of the button control.  Set it equal to true if they should have access to it, otheriwse set it equal to false.

Comment: yes i am using that .but i want to do that based on the login credentials i.e based on the role

Comment: Okay, so when you're querying the table to authenticate, you should read the value of that column and base the visible logic on that.  We really need more details of your code if you want any more specific help than that.

Comment: yes i stored the role into a session  variable and called that to the page laod of the other page...and its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
MyButton.Visible = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cinek's solution is the one you should use; however, it requires you to use set the roles appropriately into the context. It is definitely worth the effort, since you can/should store user info there.

If you do not have the option of redoing the architecture of this, you can accomplish hiding the button via the datagrid's itemdatabound event.

```
  void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) 
  {

     if((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || 
         (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
     {

        Integer intButtonColumn = ###
        Button btn = e.Item.Cells[intButtonColumn].FindControls[0];
        btn.Visible = IsUserInRole();       
     }         

  }
```